# No Render tab in Dxdiag.exe

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, rendering, directx

I have a Lenovo Z500J laptop with Geforce GT740M as GPU ,the latest Nvidia driver is installed , but when I run the Dxdiag , I do not see the Render tab , there is no render tab. I have seen this Render tab on my friends laptop (Asus Geforce GT850M) .In display tab I have Intel witch is normal . Please help me . 
This is the Dxdiag : 
[Dxdiag.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOkhM.jpg)

Comment: Do you and your friend both have the same operating system?

Comment: Yes , Win 8.1 64Bit